# I think I've shorted my Raspberry Pi using a Picoborg, but I'm not sure how? Help?

Tags: pi-zero, electronics, dc-motor, rip

So I've been trying to work out how to control a Furby Boom (2013) from a Raspberry Pi Zero W and was working on connecting the Furby's DC motor to the Pi through a Picoborg. I then ran one of the example scripts that you can get from the Picoborg website (the 4dc.py one) and the furby moved for one glorious second until everything became unresponsive. The green light is no longer on on my pi so I think I may have bricked it, however, I don't have much experience in electronics (in my second year of CS at uni) and have no idea where I went wrong.

[image: Raspberry Pi attached to picoborg]

[image: Picoborg]

[Raspberry Pi Zero W with Picoborg attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkZbp.jpg)

[Picoborg wire attachments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFXSt.jpg)
I attached the picoborg to my pi, as shown in the picture, and connected my motor to M1- and M1+ on the picoborg. The power was taken from the Furby's original power pack with takes 4AA batteries. I feel as though that may have been what shorted the pi, but online the picoborg states that it can work with up to 20V, so I thought it would be fine (nothing was soldered as I wasn't sure if I had needed to move anything and wanted to test it first).

Before adding my batteries, I plugged my Pi in via micro USB, then put in the batteries and then ran the script. The motor toggled on and ran for about a couple of seconds, and then stopped.

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong and if my Pi is salvageable? Also if you have any other advice that might help or prevent any more stupid mistakes please let me know. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: "Can anyone tell me where I went wrong" - just as a guess the terrible soldering. You have solder all over the board and bare wires.

Comment: you may have shorted something with the extra long wire ends that stick through the board ... very sloppy workmanship ... the wires look like they are not even soldered to the board